# Why does dayjs not use my selected locale?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dayjs

I'm using DayJS in my project. The user can enter some booking details, which are passed to a serverside function. This function should process the booking, but using the Dutch timezone.

No matter what I try, it keeps on using 'en' as locale. I've tried setting it globally, directly after importing the language file. Also I've tried to add it to every dayjs instance I create. Finally, I've put it all togheter, adding locale settings to every dayjs instance I have. No matter what, it doesn't give me 'nl' as timezone. I left all code in my example below.

This is my serverside code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/nl";
import isSameOrBefore from "dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore.js";
import isSameOrAfter from "dayjs/plugin/isSameOrAfter.js";
import weekday from "dayjs/plugin/weekday.js";
dayjs.locale("nl");
dayjs.extend(isSameOrBefore);
dayjs.extend(isSameOrAfter);
dayjs.extend(weekday);

const createRepeatedBookingWeek = (data, body) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    const bookingGroup = uuidv4();
    dayjs.locale("nl");

    const writeActionlog = async () => {
      const performingUserEmail = body.auth.currentUser.email;

      const performingUser = await prisma.User.findUnique({
        where: { email: performingUserEmail },
        select: { id: true },
      });

      if (performingUser) {
        await prisma.ActionLog.create({
          data: {
            actionOfUser: { connect: { id: performingUser.id } },
            performedAction: {
              connect: { name: data.actionName },
            },
          },
        });

        await prisma.$disconnect();
        return true;
      } else {
        return {
          body: JSON.stringify({
            snackbar: {
              type: "error", //success || error || warning || info
              title: "Foutcode CRBW39",
              text: "De gebruiker is niet in de database gevonden.",
            },
          }),
        };
      }
    };

    const clashingBookings = [];

    const checkForOverlappingBookings = async (query) => {
      for (const room of body.details.rooms) {
        await prisma.Booking.findMany({
          where: {
            rooms: {
              some: {
                id: room.id,
              },
            },
            OR: query,
          },
        }).then((booking) => {
          booking.forEach((element) => {
            clashingBookings.push({ ...element, room: room });
          });
        });
      }
    };

    const excludedDates = [];
    if (body.details.excludedDates && body.details.excludedDates.length != 0) {
      body.details.excludedDates.map((d) => {
        excludedDates.push(dayjs(d).locale("nl"));
      });
    }

    const checkIfExcluded = (f, t) => {
      let value = false;
      excludedDates.map((ed) => {
        if (ed.isSame(f, "day") || ed.isSame(t, "day")) {
          value = true;
        }
      });

      return value;
    };

    if (
      !body.details ||
      body.details.name == "" ||
      body.details.dateFrom == "" ||
      body.details.dateTo == ""
    ) {
      return resolve({
        body: JSON.stringify({
          snackbar: {
            type: "error", //success || error || warning || info
            title: "Foutcode CRBW98",
            text: "Invoervelden mogen niet leeg zijn.",
          },
        }),
      });
    }

    dayjs.locale("nl");

    const bookingStart = dayjs(
      `${body.details.dateFrom} ${body.details.timeFrom}`,
      "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
      "nl"
    )
      .locale("nl")
      .set("second", 0)
      .set("millisecond", 0);

    const bookingStartTS = "" + bookingStart.valueOf();
    const bookingStartOfDay = bookingStart.startOf("day");

    const bookingEnd = dayjs(
      `${body.details.dateTo} ${body.details.timeTo}`,
      "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
      "nl"
    )
      .locale("nl")
      .set("second", 0)
      .set("millisecond", 0);

    const bookingEndTS = "" + bookingEnd.valueOf();

    const repeatEnd = dayjs(
      body.details.repeatOptions.repeatUntil,
      "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "nl"
    )
      .locale("nl")
      .set("hour", 23)
      .set("minute", 59)
      .set("second", 59)
      .set("millisecond", 999);

    const repeatEndTS = "" + repeatEnd.valueOf();

    const bookingDifference = bookingEndTS - bookingStartTS;
    let dayToCheck = dayjs(bookingStart).locale("nl");

    const orConditions = [];
    const dateRanges = [];

    try {
      while (dayToCheck.isSameOrBefore(repeatEnd)) {
        let firstDayOfWeek = dayToCheck.startOf("week").locale("nl");
        const lastDayOfWeek = dayToCheck.endOf("week").locale("nl");
        console.log("locale", dayjs.locale());
        console.log("firstDayOfWeek", firstDayOfWeek);

        while (firstDayOfWeek.isSameOrBefore(lastDayOfWeek)) {
          if (
            body.details.repeatOptions.repeatOn.includes(
              firstDayOfWeek.weekday()
            )
          ) {
            const shouldBeExcluded = checkIfExcluded(
              firstDayOfWeek,
              firstDayOfWeek
            );

            if (
              !shouldBeExcluded &&
              firstDayOfWeek.isSameOrAfter(bookingStartOfDay)
            ) {
              dateRanges.push(firstDayOfWeek);
            }
          }
          firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.add(1, "day");
        }

        dayToCheck = dayToCheck.add(
          body.details.repeatOptions.interval,
          "week"
        );
      }

      // Loop through each date range
      dateRanges.forEach((dateRange) => {
        // Extract fromTS and toTS from the current date range
        const fH = body.details.timeFrom.slice(0, 2);
        const fI = body.details.timeFrom.slice(3, 5);
        const fromTS = dayjs(dateRange)
          .locale("nl")
          .set("hour", +fH)
          .set("minute", +fI)
          .valueOf();
        const toTS = dayjs(fromTS)
          .locale("nl")
          .add(bookingDifference, "ms")
          .valueOf();

        // Push into the OR conditions array
        orConditions.push({
          AND: [
            { tsFrom: { lte: "" + fromTS } },
            { tsTo: { gt: "" + fromTS } },
          ],
        });
        orConditions.push({
          AND: [{ tsFrom: { lt: "" + toTS } }, { tsTo: { gte: "" + toTS } }],
        });
        orConditions.push({
          AND: [{ tsFrom: { gte: "" + fromTS } }, { tsTo: { lte: "" + toTS } }],
        });
      });

      await checkForOverlappingBookings(orConditions);

      if (clashingBookings.length > 0) {
        let clashDates = "";
        let i = 1;
        clashingBookings.map((b) => {
          clashDates += `${b.dateFd}-${b.dateFm}-${b.dateFy} (${b.name})`;
          if (i != clashingBookings.length) {
            clashDates += ", ";
          }
          i++;
        });

        return resolve({
          body: JSON.stringify({
            snackbar: {
              type: "error", //success || error || warning || info
              title: "Foutcode CRBW220",
              text: `De reservering heeft een overlap met ${
                clashingBookings.length == 1
                  ? "een bestaande boeking"
                  : "bestaande boekingen"
              } op ${clashDates}.`,
            },
          }),
        });
      } else {
        (async () => {
          for (const dateRange of dateRanges) {
            const fH = body.details.timeFrom.slice(0, 2);
            const fI = body.details.timeFrom.slice(3, 5);

            //   Convert dayjs back to prisma format:
            const fromTS = dayjs(dateRange)
              .locale("nl")
              .set("hour", +fH)
              .set("minute", +fI)
              .valueOf();
            const toTS = dayjs(fromTS)
              .locale("nl")
              .add(bookingDifference, "ms")
              .valueOf();

            const newFrom = dayjs(fromTS).locale("nl");
            const newTo = dayjs(toTS).locale("nl");

            let newFday = newFrom.get("date");
            let newFmonth = newFrom.get("month") + 1;
            let newFyear = newFrom.get("year");
            let newTday = newTo.get("date");
            let newTmonth = newTo.get("month") + 1;
            let newTyear = newTo.get("year");

            // create the booking
            await prisma.Booking.create({
              data: {
                name: body.details.name,
                description: body.details.description,
                tsFrom: "" + fromTS,
                dateFd: `${String(newFday).padStart(2, "0")}`,
                dateFm: `${String(newFmonth).padStart(2, "0")}`,
                dateFy: "" + newFyear,
                dateFh: body.details.timeFrom.slice(0, 2),
                dateFi: body.details.timeFrom.slice(3, 5),
                tsTo: "" + toTS,
                dateTd: `${String(newTday).padStart(2, "0")}`,
                dateTm: `${String(newTmonth).padStart(2, "0")}`,
                dateTy: "" + newTyear,
                dateTh: body.details.timeTo.slice(0, 2),
                dateTi: body.details.timeTo.slice(3, 5),
              },
            }).then(async () => {
              await prisma.$disconnect();
            });

            // Pause the loop
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
          }
        })();
      }

      await writeActionlog();

      return resolve({
        body: JSON.stringify({
          snackbar: {
            type: "success", //success || error || warning || info
            title: "Succes",
            text: "De reserveringen zijn aangemaakt.",
          },
        }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      await prisma.$disconnect();
      return {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          snackbar: {
            type: "error", //success || error || warning || info
            title: "Foutcode CRBW320",
            text: "De reservering kon niet worden aangemaakt.",
          },
        }),
      };
    }
  });
};

export default createRepeatedBookingWeek;
```

**UPDATE**
I've created a minified version, still the same issue

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import checkAuth from "./utils/auth";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/nl";

dayjs.locale("nl");
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const body = await readBody(event);

  let response = (async (result) => {
    // Else perform main logic here

    try {
      const el = dayjs();
      console.log("el: ", el);

      return {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          snackbar: {
            type: "success", //success || error || warning || info
            title: "Succes",
            text: "De wijzigingen zijn opgeslagen.",
          },
        }),
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      return {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          snackbar: {
            type: "error", //success || error || warning || info
            title: "---",
            text: "De wijzigingen konden niet worden opgeslagen.",
          },
        }),
      };
    }
  })();

  return response;
});
```

Also here, `el` is returning 'en' as locale.

Comment: Reference developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/… Related but NOT a dupe, more an additional reference stackoverflow.com/q/3191664/125981

Comment: Not sure what part should be helpfull?

Comment: "This is my serverside code:" - you don't have any tags related to server code only client side JavaScript and that library.  Note you show nothing related to the binding you are importing. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import nor how it gets into your code whether via a `<link>` tag or something else

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant here. All that's used is inside this document. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs is used here, and it is working just fine. Except for the part where it changes timezone. Other dayjs modules that are imported (see dayjs.extend('PACKAGE_NAME') also work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution.

When exploring the dayjs folder in node_modules, I found out that the locale method is expecting three parameters. So I changed my code to

```
const el = dayjs().locale("nl", {}, true);
```

instead of

```
const el = dayjs().locale("nl");
```

and this creates a Dutch dayjs object.

When reading the docs, only the not working version (with only 1 param) is documented. This should be updated!

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score -1):

Reading the documentation [here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/instance-locale) you change the locale locally:

```
require('dayjs/locale/de')
dayjs().locale('de').format() // use loaded locale locally
```

In your context it will be `nl` instead on `de` in the example. As you can see you have to include the correct locale before using it

If you want to change it globally you can see [here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/changing-locale) and you will notice you just need to do the require part

Comment: But I am already setting the locale, several times. First time is directly under the imports, but also again somewhere mid-code

Comment: Also, won't "require" break my code as it is ES?

Comment: "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead"